# Continuous functions dense in $L_p(X,\mu)$ if $X$ has a special property

Tags: metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space endowed with a measure $\mu$ satisfying the following condition: all the open and closed sets of $X$ are measurable and for any measurable set $M\subset X$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set $G\supset M$ such that $\mu(G\setminus M)<\varepsilon$.

Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* proves (p. 378 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that *the set of all continuous functions* [belonging to $L_1$, I would say; not all continuous functions on $X$ are in $L_1$] *on* $X$ [with the above said property] *is everywhere dense in* $L_1(X,\mu)$. (The English translation *Introductory Real Analysis* (p. 381 [here](http://librarum.org/book/10022/195)) proves that the set of all continuous functions on $X$ is everywhere dense if $L_1(X,\mu)$ has the following property: all the open and closed sets of $X$ are measurable and $\mu(M)=\inf_{M\subset G}\mu(G)$, which is a similar property: I would say that it is equivalent to the property above if $\mu(X)< \infty$ but not equivalent, though implied, if $\mu(X)=\infty$.)

From Kolmgorov-Fomin's proof, since I think that $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is measurable because of its continuity and the above said property of $X$ and $|\varphi_\varepsilon|^p$ is integrable because it is bounded by the integrable function taking the values 1 for $x\in G_M$, where $\mu(G_M)<\infty$ (if I correctly understand the book) and 0 elsewhere, I would say that the same holds of any $L_p(X,\mu)$, $p\geq 1$, where $X$ has the above property, i.e. the set of all continuous functions belonging to $L_p(X,\mu)$ is everywhere dense in $L_p(X,\mu)$.

Am I right? I thank anybody for any answer!